# Java Set HashSet

Tags: java, коллекции

Имеется HashSet объектов из них хотелось бы что бы хеш объекта и его уникальность оценивалась только по определённому его полю а не по всему объекту...Это нужно что бы не создавать вторую такую же коллекцию с ссылками на элементы первой...Можно ли это как-то добиться?

Comment: Переопределите у объекта функцию hashCode и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 2):

Пример (код сгенерированый IntelliJ):

```
public class ExampleObj {

    private int id;
    private String msg;

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ExampleObj that = (ExampleObj ) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Пример с библиотекой [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"msg"})
public class ExampleObj {

    private int id;
    private String msg;

}
```